# Stop co-routine with a toggle button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a co-routine that is triggered when the bool of a toggle button changes, when the bool is changed again that co-routine should be stopped and another one should start. This is my code:

```
    public class thermoPowerControlPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    private ThermoElectric thermo;

    public bool toggleBool1;
    public int temperature;
    private int tempUp = 10;
    private int tempDown = 1;


    public thermoPowerControlPanel (){
        temperature = 100;
    }


    public void turbine1State (bool toggleBool1) {

        if (toggleBool1 == false) {
            Debug.Log (toggleBool1);
            Invoke("ReduceTemperatureEverySecond", 1f);
        }

        if (toggleBool1 == true) {
            Debug.Log (toggleBool1);
            Invoke("IncreaseTemperatureEverySecond", 1f);
        }
    }


    private void ReduceTemperatureEverySecond()
    {
        if (toggleBool1 == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("I was told to stop reducing the temperature.");
            return;
        }
        temperature = temperature - tempDown;
        Debug.Log (temperature);
            Invoke("ReduceTemperatureEverySecond", 1f);
    }

    private void IncreaseTemperatureEverySecond()
    {
        if (toggleBool1 == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("I was told to stop increasing the temperature.");
            return;
        }
        temperature = temperature + tempUp;
        Debug.Log (temperature);
        Invoke("ReduceTemperatureEverySecond", 1f);
    }
}
```

When the function turbine1State(bool t1) receives the first bool (false), the routine decreaseTemperatureEverySecond() starts but it stops immediately after, sending the Debug.Log message, it should keep reducing the temperature until the bool (activated by the toggle button) turned true.
.

Can you help?

Comment: search on a 1000 questions on "stop coroutine"

Comment: I think the problem is in the bool  if condition, I have the code to stop it, but it is never activated

Comment: Due to Joe Blow's advice I changed the code to stop using co-routines.

Comment: For some unknow reason it seems that the toggleBool1 changes to true when ReduceTemperatureEverySecond() is invoked..

Comment: hi @growanimation .. can you please explain in simple terms, **what you are trying to achieve** then it will be easy to write the code

Comment: It is working now, it was a problem in the inspector.

Comment: I used your previous suggestion and I got the invoke to work.

Comment: OK I will show you how you would ACTUALLY DO THIS OK!  :)

Comment: What I want is to have a temperature variable that is decreased or increased every second depending on the toggle button.

Comment: It starts as 100, when the bool goes off it starts decreasing, when the bool goes back on it starts increasing, the limits for the temperature is 0-100.

Comment: are you completely OK now?  pls also see my answer for another way of looking at it.

Comment: I need to try it now and see if I can make it work. I tough we were going in a different way.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much.

Comment: lol no worries.  don't forget, never use coroutines!

Comment: What are coroutines? Never heard of them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It is this easy!

```
 public Toggle tog;  // DONT FORGET TO SET IN EDITOR
```

in `Start` ...

```
 InvokeRepeating( "Temp", 1f, 1f );
```

... and then ...

```
private void Temp()
 {
 if (tog.isOn)
     temperature = temperature + 1;
 else
     temperature = temperature - 1;
 
 // also, ensure it is never outside of 0-100
 temperature = Mathf.Clamp(temperature, 0,100);
 }
```

If you ever need to "totally stop" that action (both up and down), just do this

```
 CancelInvoke("Temp");
```

So easy!

---

NOTE purely FYI, the other pattern I explained is this:

```
 bool some flag;
 Invoke("Temp", 1f);
 private void Temp()
   {
   if (some flag is tripped) stop doing this
   .. do something ..
   Invoke( ..myself again after a second .. )
   }
```

In real life, it is usually better to "keep Invoking yourself" rather than use InvokeRepeating.

In this simple example, just use InvokeRepeating, and then CancelInvoke.

Comment: But I don't need to Invoke the function itself again because now I am using the InvokeRepeating correct?

Comment: Yes, that is **one billion percent correct**.  I only mentioned that "other method" as a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop coroutine only by it name.

Just try some like `StartCoroutine("increaseTemperature");` and then `StopCoroutine("increaseTemperature");`.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

There are a number of ways to call `StartCoroutine`.  You can "stop" a coroutines **IF** you start it with the "string" method, like this `StartCoroutine("FunctionNameAsStringHere");`  If you start it like this `StartCoroutine(FunctionNameAsStringHere());` you cannot stop it by name.

(You can also access the actual enumerator to stop coroutines, but that is far beyond the scope of a beginner using coroutines.)

Comment: I just did it, but still not working, i have the same problem. I will edit the question with the new code.

Comment: This answer is not true. You can stop coroutines also by referenced `Coroutine` object or current returned `IEnumerator`. Check the overloaded method `MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine`.

Comment: Updated start/stop corutines calling in your code, as i understend - it works http://pastebin.com/k9R5YgFr

Comment: jezz you might be interested in this subtle issue http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1119978/view.html @JerrySwitalski fascinating!